# kernels are learnable in tf.nn.conv2d?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am implementing a custom convolution layer as follow to understand the customizable layer:

```
class StandardizedConv2DWithCall(layers.Conv2D):
    def convolution_op(self, inputs, kernel,dtype=float):
    
        output=tf.nn.conv2d(
           inputs,
           kernel,
           padding="SAME",
           strides=list(self.strides),
           name=self.__class__.__name__,
        )

        return output
```

Is the "kernel" learnable? in other words, the "kernel" is what makes the network try to adjust in each epoch?

When I run the code taken from [here](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/subclassing_conv_layers/).

```
# Model / data parameters
num_classes = 10
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Scale images to the [0, 1] range
x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
# Make sure images have shape (28, 28, 1)
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)
print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], "train samples")
print(x_test.shape[0], "test samples")

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape),
        StandardizedConv2DWithCall(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        StandardizedConv2DWithOverride(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.5),
        layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"),
    ]
)
```

It seems that the network does not learn as if the kernel is just a 3x3 matrix with a constant values that in each iteration (back propagation) is differentiated to $0$ and so, has no effect to learning and a simple convolution is happening not a learning process.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you training the network? Does the model train as expected if you replace your StandardizedConv2D layers with ordinary Conv2D layers?

Comment: @Lynn, it is training but I do not know if it does some training.